# Apache not loading view inside another view of codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, ubuntu

I wrote a codeigniter app and deployed in apache. after checking in browser, single view controllers are loading very fine. but i made all css headers and some session management codes into one php file named header.php. So i had to call this php view in every other views. But, browser shows

> Unable to load the requested file: Header/header.php

i wrote this line in my all views to call header view
`<?php $this->load->view('Header/header.php'); ?>`.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: as the error is very clear. make sure header.php file is inside Header folder.

Comment: Yes, i made it sure it is inside the Header folder. The actual location from my project folder is application->modules->Header->views->header.php. could you please tell me if there anything wrong??@prasannaputtaswamy

Comment: is it hmvc or mvc?

Comment: it is hmvc @prasannaputtaswamy

Comment: thanks for the support @prasannaputtaswamy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found solution. When running CI app in localhost, it is not that case sensitive. actually i tested it in windows. Windows is not much case sensitive in directory names. But, when CI app deployed in apache ubuntu it becomes more case sensitive. Inside every module, CI models, controllers, views folder names should be in lowercase. In my case, views folder of Header module was Uppercase.